# How much are banks allowed to intrude in peoples' private life?

Tags: privacy, banking

Europe, but I think my question could be applicable over the Western world. I saw an online notice about a policy change by Natwest in the UK. Now people who want to [withdraw cash](https://supportcentre.natwest.com/Banking-near-me/Withdrawals/913244082/What-is-the-maximum-amount-I-can-withdraw-from-a-branch.htm)  have to explain why they want the cash and provide the relevant documentation. I wondered why a private entity is allowed to ask their customers detail about their business and their private life in order to fulfil their service.

I assume that their action is legal, therefore I would like to know under the current legislation how far can they get into people private life.  How much can banks ask to their customers under the threat of freezing their money or denying a service?

Comment: The banks are concerned about money laundering and drug dealing. Cash deposits of over $10,000 in the US are questioned as well. The banks are interested because they are required to report them.

Comment: How much can they ask? Just as much as you have agreed. Read the fine print.

Comment: This reminds me of a running gag about "Bob's Bank" on Garrison Keillor's radio variety show called "A Prairie Home Companion" for many, many years. An example is at https://www.prairiehome.org/story/1999/12/18/bobs-bank.html The gag  was an ode to small town pettiness and snoopiness.

Comment: @JonCuster Reporting something that sounds suspicious is quite different than actively investigating their customers. If really money laundering and drug dealing it means that they are carrying out preventing investigations as if they were public officers.

Comment: @mustermax - yes, because in the US the government but the burden on the banks to deal with it or risk being in court on money laundering charges.

Comment: In practice, if you lie to your bank when making a withdrawal, they are not going to send private investigators to follow you and see what you really spend the money on, although they may inform police of suspicious transactions. They do their legal duty in the way that minimizes liability and costs.

Comment: @Greendrake Fine print is written by lawyers, for lawyers. It is usually intentionally vague, and has enough weasel words to make it virtually impossible to know exactly what they will or can do, and what they won't or can't do.

Comment: @Greendrake Reading the fine print changes little. As things stand having a bank account is de facto mandatory.

Comment: @JonCuster I suspect this is less about money laundering and more about protecting vulnerable customers from phishing scams where a criminal has convinced a customer (often an elderly customer) that their account has been “compromised” and is getting them to move the money in cash to the scammer.